# React `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React and running into this error from following a tutorial

```
 react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: CartItem: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop. (https://reactjs.org/link/special-props)
    at CartItem (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:206:5)
    at div
    at div
    at Cart (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:390:5)
    at header
    at div
    at App
```

I was originally using key={item.id}, but now trying to use index in map and still receiving it, putting the code into a sandbox doesn't produce it
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-intro-forked-ffbnt0?file=/src/App.js

Here is the code locally
app.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Cart from './cart';
import './App.css';

const cartItems = [
  {id:1,name:"Pepperoni Pizza", price: 5.50, qty:1},
  {id:2,name:"Ham & Cheese Pizza", price: 6.00, qty:5},
  {id:3,name:"Supreme Pizza", price: 9.00, qty:3}
]
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Cart baseItems={cartItems}/>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

cart.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "./Cart.css"
import CartItem from './CartItem';

function Cart({ baseItems }) {
    const initState = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('items'));
    const [items, setItems] = useState(initState || baseItems)

    const cartTotal = baseItems.reduce(
        (total, item) => (
            total + item.qty * item.price
        ), 0
    ).toFixed(2)

    const updateQty = (id, updatedQty) => {
        const newItems = items.map(item => {
            if (item.id === id) {
                return { ...item, qty: updatedQty }
            }
            return item;
        })
        setItems(newItems);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items))
    }, [items]);
    return (
        <div className="Cart">
            <h1 className="Cart-Title"> Shopping Cart</h1>
            <div className="Cart-Items">
                {items.map((item, index) => {
                    return <CartItem key={index} updateItemQuantity={updateQty} {...item} />
                })}
            </div>
            <h2 className="Cart-Total">
                Total = ${cartTotal}
            </h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Cart;
```

and CartItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./CartItem.css"
function CartItem({name, price, id, qty,updateItemQuantity }) {
    const AddAmt = (amt) => {
        updateItemQuantity(id,qty+amt)
    }
    return (
        <div className="Cart-Item">
            <div>{name}</div>
            <div>${price}</div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() =>AddAmt(-1)} disabled={qty <= 1}>-</button>
                {qty}
                <button onClick={() => AddAmt(1)}>+</button>
            </div>
            <div>Total = ${qty*price}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CartItem;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was Console Nina... Uninstalling this fixed the issue, found this by using my eyes
[image]

Don't really know why it shows as null there, but at least it's fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).